# How to modified this useState in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I define the state hooks like this:

```
const [list, setList] = useState(
  [] as { name: string; value: string }[],
)
```

I also get an array here:

```
const arrayFortheList = ['a','b','c']
```

Here is my work:

```
setList(
 arrayFortheList.map((e):void => {name: e, value: ''})
)
```

The error message is also here:
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {paramName, paramValue}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How can I correct it?

Comment: Looks like the error is in rendering.

Comment: Can you include more of your code in your question that includes where you use the `list` variable?

Comment: sorry is my mistake, I solve this stupid problem. But I get another problem which is  how can I render it as List for user to onchange it value?

Answer (score 1):

You just made a very common syntax error in your arrow function. For returning an object you have to add an extra `()` like:

```
setList(
 arrayFortheList.map(e => ({name: e, value: ''}))
                          ^                    ^
)
```

Otherwise `{}` means a block without returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @gazdagergo's answer, you could `JSON.stringify()` your object.

```
setList(arrayFortheList.map((e):void => JSON.stringify({name: e, value: ''})))
```

Then to read your data, you would `JSON.parse()` to retrieve the object.

```
var list_state = JSON.parse(list)
```

Comment: then we have the question: what's the advantage on stringify it?

Comment: There is no real advantage, it is simply an option you could take. The only “advantage” I could see is that JSON.stringify({ x: 1 })) is more readable than ({ x: 1 })